# PHP imap_body to array

Tags: php, arrays, base64, imap

I want to make an array of the attachment files with `imap_body`. This is the example of how I get the `imap_body`:

```
--001a11c2a20cbdfb1c04f7653888
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11c2a20cbdfb1b04f7653887

--001a11c2a20cbdfb1b04f7653887
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

bmV3IHRlc3QNCg0KcmVkIGlzIGZpcnN0DQoNCltpbWFnZTog16rXnteV16DXlCDXnteV15jXkdei
16ogMV0NCg0KDQp0aGFuIGdvZXMgYmxhY2sNCg0KW2ltYWdlOiDXqtee15XXoNeUINee15XXmNeR
16LXqiAyXQ0KDQphbmQgdGhhbiByb2kNCg0KW2ltYWdlOiDXqtee15XXoNeUINee15XXmNeR16LX
qiAzXQ0K
--001a11c2a20cbdfb1b04f7653887
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

new test
=
red is first

3D"=D7=AA=D7=9E=D7=95=D7=A0=D7=

than goes black

3D"=D7=AA=D7=9E=D7=95=D7=A0=D7=94
and than roi

--001a11c2a20cbdfb1b04f7653887--
--001a11c2a20cbdfb1c04f7653888
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="black.jpeg"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="black.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: 
X-Attachment-Id: ii_1457a2ac29603915

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAABtbnRyUkdC
IFhZWiAHzgACAAkABgAxAABhY3NwTVNGVAAAAABJRUMgc1JHQgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAA
AADTLUhQICAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABFj
cHJ0AAABUAAAADNkZXNjAAABhAAAAGx3dHB0AAAB8AAAABRia3B0AAACBAAAABRyWFlaAAACGAAA
.....
.....the base 64 is very long so i cut it for the example
.....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--001a11c2a20cbdfb1c04f7653888
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="red.jpeg"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="red.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: 
X-Attachment-Id: ii_1457a2a811de3322

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYF
BgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBDAQICAgICAgUDAwUKBwYHCgoKCgoK
CgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgr/wAARCAHNAmcDAREA
.....
..... again the base 64 is long so i cut it for the example
.....
QBAEAQBAEAQBAEAQBAEAQBAf/9k=
--001a11c2a20cbdfb1c04f7653888
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="roi.jpg"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="roi.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: 
X-Attachment-Id: ii_1457a2aef606ba6d

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD//gAEKgD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABt
bnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH3AABABkAAwApADlhY3NwQVBQTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
9tYAAQAAAADTLWxjbXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAApkZXNjAAAA/AAAAF5jcHJ0AAABXAAAAAt3dHB0AAABaAAAABRia3B0AAABfAAAABRyWFla
...
....
.... the end look like this
pgaKQVBLlxaYlxXSPEQiyvtAWclft/Mdo/M1y6Z0e8UZncAksFR+JYqv4ndXfiIc/ggxf6Ubq/Sm
C/0oX/xQRj8ENoxPX4oAdPxCjRUuXiOF3LzFcS25pwbFcPN1CLw8o32RWQZpGDKtbGyOoizQ4hWZ
tNSefA3NzSDcrMHC47gog4WZpN49zVmz1f/Z
--001a11c2a20cbdfb1c04f7653888--
```

I build a function that will decode the content to utf-8. Now I just need to replace the images with there base64. Now it look like this:

```
<img src="cid:ii_1457a2ac29603915" />
and i want to replace it like this
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,...." />
```

So if I would have the array I need it will be easy to make the replace. I want to make an array that will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => black.jpeg
            [cid] => ii_1457a2ac29603915
            [Content-Disposition] => inline
            [encoding] => base64 (get it from "Content-Transfer-Encoding")
            (
                [file] => the base 64 of the file / image
            ) 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filename] => red.jpeg
            [cid] => ii_1457a2a811de3322
            [Content-Disposition] => inline
            [encoding] => base64 (get it from "Content-Transfer-Encoding")
            (
                [file] => the base 64 of the file / image
            ) 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [filename] => roi.jpg
            [cid] => ii_1457a2aef606ba6d
            [Content-Disposition] => inline
            [encoding] => base64 (get it from "Content-Transfer-Encoding")
            (
                [file] => the base 64 of the file / image
            ) 
        )
)
```

Comment: OK, so you're retrieving the entire body[], and want to split it up and look at each part. Why do you do that instead of retrieving each part singly, ie. body[1], body[2] and body[3]? Fetch bodystructure will give you the content-types etc.

Comment: @arnt no i just want to get an array with the details about the attachment files and than i will use str_replace where cid equal to the cid in the array so replace it with the base64 of the image | edit: i use bodystructure but it doesnt give me the "cid"